# Is Nginx plus sticky route method good for route based load balancing?

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I have posted this problem earlier:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34977074/how-to-use-load-balancer-for-sockets

Basically my requirement is to send a particular url request to specific app server through load balancer.So i am looking for some kind of load balancer which can complete my requirement.

I was reading about nginx plus and found this link.
https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/load-balancer/

There is one concept of **sticky route** in this documentation.I just want to know can it serve my purpose?

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you need can be simply accomplished by [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/), which does a much more professional load balancing than NginX.

It has a feature where you can direct specific requests based on the `URI` to specific backend server, using `ACL`. Here is a very simple example (from default config file):

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# main frontend which proxys to the backends
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
frontend  main *:5000
    acl url_static       path_beg       -i /static /images /javascript /stylesheets
    acl url_static       path_end       -i .jpg .gif .png .css .js

    use_backend static          if url_static
    default_backend             app

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# static backend for serving up images, stylesheets and such
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
backend static
    balance     roundrobin
    server      static 127.0.0.1:4331 check

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# round robin balancing between the various backends
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
backend app
    balance     roundrobin
    server  app1 127.0.0.1:5001 check
    server  app2 127.0.0.1:5002 check
    server  app3 127.0.0.1:5003 check
    server  app4 127.0.0.1:5004 check
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

For more reading, check the [official HAProxy Docs](http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.6/doc/configuration.txt)

Answer (score 1):

The sticky routes (aka sticky sessions or session persistence) is about keeping the client connected to the same upstream. This is helpful if you're load balancing logged in user sessions, payment transaction, etc.

I believe what you're looking for is location based routing. This would route requests such as /payment/* to one group of upstreams, and /login/* to another, etc. There's a section about this on the [Microservices Solutions](https://www.nginx.com/solutions/microservices/) page.

What you'd want to do is define several upstream groups and then proxy_pass to these upstreams within different location blocks. I'll provide a brief example here:

```
upstream payments {
     server backend1.example.com
     server backend2.example.com
}

upstream login {
     server backend3.example.com
     server backend4.example.com
}

server {
     ...
     location /payments {
          proxy_pass http://payments;
     }

     location /login {
          proxy_pass http://login;
     }
}
```

- If you have questions specifically about NGINX Plus I'd encourage you to use the provided commercial support channels.

(Disclaimer: I work at NGINX.)